# How to make a table smaller?

Tags: tables, longtable

I am going make a table smaller in a paper which I am going to submit to a journal. I used `\small` but it does not make it small enough ?

Comment: How about `\tiny`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: If the journal have requirements about the layout and presentation, I'd be surprised if they let you change the type size in the table.

Answer (score 8):

With no information or example in your question it is hard to give advice but before choosing font sizes smaller than `\small` (eg via `\tiny` or by using `\resizebox` or `\scalebox`) you should look at ways to reduce the table width while maintaining the font size (so keeping the data more easily legible, especially on paper which apparently doesn't have a zoom function).

You can reduce the inter-column space with

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{something}
```

You can force some columns to be narrower by changing `l` to

```
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{some width}
```

You can (perhaps) rotate, shrink or re-word the headings if the table headings are forcing the columns to be wider than needed for the data.

Comment: Add @{} at beginning and end of the column definitions.

Answer (score 6):

with package `graphicx`:

```
\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
 ... your table code ...
}
```

Comment: No sure if this is the best possible solution because is scales the type, which may make it look bad.