# Long and rescaled xtable

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

Is there a way to use `scalebox` along with `tabular.environment='longtable'` when printing a long and wide xtable?

When I give both of them I get an error:

```
Running xelatex.exe on my_file.tex...failed
```

Comment: hm, would be helpful if you'd provide the code...

Comment: This should be tagged as "latex" or "tex"

Comment: It's not a matter of code. Does scalebox work with longtable (using the xtable package)? See also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764013/latex-table-is-spilling-over-page-on-right

Comment: The main property of a longtable is that it can span multiple pages, thus there is no single box - so you can't use scalebox on it.

Comment: ok. Is there another way of reducing the width of a longtable?

Comment: @gd047 You can use a smaller font or change the column widths or inter column space see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101748/how-to-make-a-table-smaller/101762#101762

Comment: You can also use an at-expression to reduce the width of the first and the last columns: `\begin{tabular}{@{}<stuf>@{}} <more stuff> \end{tabular}`. If your tabular has "decorations" such as vertical rules, you could remove them.

Comment: The table is supposed to be created using the xtable R package, and code like this: my.table <- xtable(df, caption="A Very Long Table", label="ALongTable"); print(my.table, tabular.environment="longtable", floating=FALSE)