# Dificult using LTXtable

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, ltxtable

I have a script in R that build a report in LaTeX. Sometimes, this report has very long and very wide table, so, after some research I decided try `ltxtable`. My problem is that I didn't get how it works.

I have this LaTeX code for the report:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ltxtable, tabularx, longtable}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=1cm,right=3cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\title{CP 68 - Estatístico}
\author{Rodrigo Coster - 1141783-01}
\begin{document}
\textbf{ \begin{center}{\LARGE Informações referentes ao CP 68 - Estatístico }\end{center} } 
\section*{Informações sobre processos} 
 Relação do quantitativo de candidatos convocados para cada processo selecionado  
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{'table.tex'}
\section*{Informações sobre fila de espera} 
 Este CP não possui mais candidatos habilitados.  
\end{document}
```

And, in the same folder, the file `table.tex`:

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c{1cm}|}
\begin{center}
 \hline  
 \textbf{\textbf{Processo}} & \textbf{Vagas} & \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Convocados} & \textbf{Exercicio ok} \\ \hline  
 \textbf{001.010726.12.8} & 2 & 13/04/2012 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline  
\end{center}
\end{longtable}
```

After run, in console appears:

```
("C:\relatorios\Concursos\20130312 - CP 68 - Estatistico.aux")
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
Enter file name:
```

I tried a lot of file names. For most of them, he ask for the name again. If I type `table.tex` I get this error:

```
(C:\relatorios\Concursos\table.tex
! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.
<to be read again> 
                   &
l.1 \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c{1cm}|}

?
```

I already tried put `\begin{center}` in the first line, but didn't work.

EDIT:

Anothe `table.tex`:

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline  
 \textbf{\textbf{Área}} & \textbf{Convocados} & \textbf{Não ingressou} & \textbf{Para convocar} & \textbf{Manifestou interesse} & \textbf{Exercicio ok} \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Administração e economia               } &   8 &  6 & 0 &  0 &   2 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Anos iniciais dos ciclos de formação   } & 474 & 80 & 0 & 13 & 381 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Artes visuais                          } &  45 &  8 & 2 &  2 &  33 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Biologia                               } &   1 &  0 & 0 &  0 &   1 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Ciências da computação                 } &   2 &  1 & 0 &  0 &   1 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Ciências físicas, químicas e biológicas} &  72 & 12 & 0 &  1 &  59 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Ciências sócio-históricas              } &  48 & 11 & 0 &  2 &  35 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Dança                                  } &  17 &  6 & 0 &  0 &  11 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Deficiência mental                     } &  40 &  5 & 0 &  0 &  35 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Deficiência visual                     } &   4 &  1 & 0 &  0 &   3 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Educação de surdos                     } &   6 &  3 & 0 &  0 &   3 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Educação física/rede escolar           } & 134 & 26 & 0 &  1 & 107 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Educação infantil                      } & 123 & 17 & 1 &  2 & 103 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Filosofia                              } &   7 &  0 & 0 &  0 &   7 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Física                                 } &   1 &  0 & 0 &  0 &   1 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Geografia                              } &  56 & 15 & 1 &  2 &  38 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{História                               } &  51 & 15 & 0 &  0 &  36 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Língua espanhola                       } &  33 &  8 & 0 &  1 &  24 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Língua francesa                        } &   3 &  1 & 0 &  0 &   2 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Língua inglesa                         } &  38 &  9 & 1 &  0 &  28 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Língua portuguesa                      } &  81 & 22 & 1 &  0 &  58 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Matemática                             } & 104 & 26 & 1 &  1 &  76 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Música                                 } &  51 & 17 & 0 &  1 &  33 \\ \hline  
 \textbf{Teatro                                 } &   5 &  0 & 0 &  0 &   5 \\ \hline  
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: You can not put `\begin{center}` inside `longtable` )or any other latex tabular environment` Justdelete those lines. `c{1cm}` is also a syntax error latex `c` columns do not take a length parameter.

Comment: If this is primarily a table of numeric data you do not want `ltxtable`/`tabularx` as that allows entries in a column to wrap over several lines but you can not do line breaking in numbers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed the `\begin{center}`, `\end{center}` and `{1cm}`. Now it ask the file name several times (actualy, 4). After the 4th, the .pdf file is created (and with the table! \o/). You know why (and how to solve)? My problem with the width is in the title line (some tables has more than 5 columns)

Comment: Probably the quotes are confusing things try changing `{'table.tex'}` to `{table}`  But ltxtable will do _nothing_ on this example other than be slower than a normal tabular. see this for ways of making tables narrower http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101748/how-to-make-a-table-smaller/101762#101762

Comment: It worked! I added another `table.tex`, with more columns. I read you post, but didn't get how to adapt it to `ltxtable` :/

Comment: I wouldn't use ltxtable, just use a normal tabular and arrange that it fits the page width by changing the font size or using p{} columns or using different formatting for the headers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need for that table to be wide, you just need to make sure the table width is not dominated by the headers. It is much better to do that by hand than rely on `tabularx` / `ltxtable` which knows nothing about the table structure.

here I rotated the headings but there are other possibilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable,graphicx,array}

\newcommand\rothead[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1\ }}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\bfseries\raggedright}p{5cm}|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline  
 \rothead{Área} & \rothead{Convocados} & \rothead{Não ingressou} &
 \rothead{Para convocar} & \rothead{Manifestou interesse} & \rothead{Exercicio ok} \\ \hline  
 Administração e economia              &   8 &  6 & 0 &  0 &   2 \\ \hline  
 Anos iniciais dos ciclos de formação  & 474 & 80 & 0 & 13 & 381 \\ \hline  
 Artes visuais                         &  45 &  8 & 2 &  2 &  33 \\ \hline  
 Biologia                              &   1 &  0 & 0 &  0 &   1 \\ \hline  
 Ciências da computação                &   2 &  1 & 0 &  0 &   1 \\ \hline  
 Ciências físicas, químicas e biológicas &  72 & 12 & 0 &  1 &  59 \\ \hline  
 Ciências sócio-históricas             &  48 & 11 & 0 &  2 &  35 \\ \hline  
 Dança                                 &  17 &  6 & 0 &  0 &  11 \\ \hline  
 Deficiência mental                    &  40 &  5 & 0 &  0 &  35 \\ \hline  
 Deficiência visual                    &   4 &  1 & 0 &  0 &   3 \\ \hline  
 Educação de surdos                    &   6 &  3 & 0 &  0 &   3 \\ \hline  
 Educação física/rede escolar          & 134 & 26 & 0 &  1 & 107 \\ \hline  
 Educação infantil                     & 123 & 17 & 1 &  2 & 103 \\ \hline  
 Filosofia                             &   7 &  0 & 0 &  0 &   7 \\ \hline  
 Física                                &   1 &  0 & 0 &  0 &   1 \\ \hline  
 Geografia                             &  56 & 15 & 1 &  2 &  38 \\ \hline  
 História                              &  51 & 15 & 0 &  0 &  36 \\ \hline  
 Língua espanhola                      &  33 &  8 & 0 &  1 &  24 \\ \hline  
 Língua francesa                       &   3 &  1 & 0 &  0 &   2 \\ \hline  
 Língua inglesa                        &  38 &  9 & 1 &  0 &  28 \\ \hline  
 Língua portuguesa                     &  81 & 22 & 1 &  0 &  58 \\ \hline  
 Matemática                            & 104 & 26 & 1 &  1 &  76 \\ \hline  
 Música                                &  51 & 17 & 0 &  1 &  33 \\ \hline  
 Teatro                                &   5 &  0 & 0 &  0 &   5 \\ \hline  
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a simple typography tip, as I liked David's technical answer but not the looks (I don't like to turn my head to read headers). Although also not a very good solution you can use abbreviations, turn the table data around or use symbols (which you can explain in the caption or in the text).

[image]

Comment: Yes I'd have probably suggested abbreviating the headers but I wasn't sure what they all meant so rotating them was linguistically safer:-) (+1)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure maybe Paul can translate them for us:)