# How to fix a table that is too wide for margins?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, margins, memoir

I have created a table that is too wide for the margins. What I tried to do was implement `\hspace*{-50pt}` before `\begin{tabular}` and `\hspace{-50pt}` after `\end{tabluar}`. Which gets rid of the `overfull \hbox` message but the table is right to the edge of the paper. Is there way to scale it down so it centers and is not at the edge of the paper? Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[size=pocket,trim,bleed]{createspace}
%\usepackage[paperwidth=4.25in, paperheight=6.875in,bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{type1cm}
%\usepackage{lettrine}

%\checkandfixthelayout

% See the ``Memoir customise'' template for some common customisations
% Don't forget to read the Memoir manual: memman.pdf

%\title{TITLE OF BOOK}
%\author{NAME OF AUTHOR}
%\date{} % Delete this line to display the current date

%% BEGIN TITLE

\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
  \null
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}\leavevmode
    \normalfont
    {\LARGE\raggedleft \@author\par}%
    \hrulefill\par
    {\huge\raggedright \@title\par}%
    \vskip 1cm
%    {\Large \@date\par}%
  \end{center}%
  \vfill
  \null
  \cleardoublepage
  }
\makeatother
\author{AUTHOR}
%\author{NAME OF AUTHOR}
\title{TITLE}
%\date{}










%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT

\begin{document}
\pdftitle{TITLE}
\pdfauthor{AUTHOR}
\pdfsubject{SUBJECT}
\chapterstyle{bianchi}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage


\maketitle






\frontmatter

\null\vfill

\begin{flushleft}

Copyright \copyright  
%\textit{TITLE}

All rights reserved.

ISBN: 

ISBN--13: 
\bigskip





\end{flushleft}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\clearpage
\tableofcontents

    \chapter{[Chapter name]}
    \begin{figure}
\hspace*{-50pt}
    \begin{tabular}{l l l l }
        Open & $512$ & P/E & $21.0$ \\
        Range & $500-598$ & Mkt.Cap & $100.5$B\\
        52 Week high/low & $456-612$ & \# of shares & $256$m\\
        VOL/Avg. & 355458760/2914515 & Beta & $1.02$ \\
        Ask & $510.25$ & Inst. Own & $45$\% \\
        Div/Yield & - & Bid & $511.25$ \\
        & & EPS & 25.07 
        \end{tabular}
        \hspace{-50pt}
        \caption{TEXT}
    \end{figure}


\mainmatter
\sloppy
%Input all of the chapter here


\backmatter


\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101748/how-to-make-a-table-smaller

Comment: just use `\small` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I use `\small` then where would that go? Is it before the table?

Comment: well just so the bits you want to go small are in its scope:) just after `\begin{figure}` for example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I inserted `\small` before `\begin{figure}` and it hasn't made a difference. I tried using `\resizebox{}{}{}` but gives me an error "Not in outer par mode."

Comment: BTW: @gekkostate: why `figure` and not `table`? And why those `-50pt`? Also try to lookup `\centerfloat` in the `memoir` manual

Comment: `\small` goes inside the float, but before `\begin{tabular}`

Comment: @gekkostate your MWE isn't very minimal (it doesn't run here) do you really need non standard packages to show the problem?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need the createspace package because I am using that to format my book and I don't think this problem will happen if it was normal size paper. I tried what daleif suggested and it seems to have centered the table but now I get underfull `\hbox` and overfull `\hbox` at the same time. EDIT: I tried `\tiny` that fixes everything but `\tiny` is _too_ small. Is there anything in between `\small` and `\tiny`?

Comment: By we don't have access to `createspace`, plus it may or may not be relevant to your problem.

Comment: @gekkostate see the other suggestions in the link in the first comment, you can change column widths or inter-column space as well as changing font size, but you could make an article class example and you set \textwidth to the right size

Comment: If you got an "Not in outer par mode." error, you most probably tried to resize the `figure` environment. Try `\begin{figure}\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}...\end{tabluar}}\end{figure}`, if you really want to use `\resizebox` (which I would not recommend!)

Comment: @benwilfut: not for a book to be published. Rescaling ends up with text in all kinds of sizes instead of the specific set of sizes often set by the publisher. In many cases a rewrite may be needed.

Comment: @daleif: That's why I said that I wouldn't recommend it :D

Comment: @benwilfut: ahh, sorry missed that ;-)

Comment: I have used `\tiny` which seems to make it work and I guess, I will be going with that. If I am not satisfied with it later, I'll just try the links and tips that you have provided. Thanks a bunch for your help :)

Comment: @daleif: no harm done, and I'm glad that we agree on the issue ;)

Comment: @gekkostate: there are several other things you ought to fix in that example: (1) units, typeset using `siunitx`, (2) does this indicate a range? `$500-598$`, if so write it as 500--598, minus is the wrong dash in this case.

Comment: Between `\tiny` and `\small` there is `\footnotesize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `createspace`?  If I use the `geometry` settings, this works:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
%\usepackage[size=pocket,trim,bleed]{createspace}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.25in, paperheight=6.875in,%bindingoffset=.75in
showframe]{geometry}
% the 'bindingoffset' seems huge for such narrow margins
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% \usepackage{tgtermes}% ..?
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}

\begin{document}

Here is the table:

\begin{table}[!hb]
\footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l l l l}
    Open & $512$ & P/E & $21.0$ \\
    Range & $500-598$ & Mkt.Cap & $100.5$B\\
    52 Week hi./lo. & $456-612$ & \# of shares & $256$m\\
    VOL/Avg. & {\scriptsize 355458760/2914515} & Beta & $1.02$ \\
    Ask & $510.25$ & Inst. Own & $45$\% \\
    Div/Yield & - & Bid & $511.25$ \\
    & & EPS & 25.07
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{TEXT}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: createspace is a package that I am using to format my book.

Comment: I have tried `\footnotesize` and that seems to do it. Thanks a lot for your help. I guess `\resizebox{}{}{}` was not necessary after all.

Comment: @gekkostate -- glad it worked!